# Outdated version of Zend Engine API

Tags: api, symfony, mamp

I am hosting a website, using the Symfony framework, on a MAMP server on my Mac, and I'm trying to generate bundles automatically with the help of the terminal.

If it is relevant in any way, here is what I try to type into the terminal:

> php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini php
>   app/console generate:bundle

And here is the error I get:

> XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220100525. The Zend Engine API
>   version 220090626 which is installed, is outdated.
>
> Could not open input file: php

Do any of you have an idea of how I could update the Zend Engine API or otherwise fix my problem? That would be of HUGE help!

**Edit:**

Thanks to the help of whistlergreg I've gotten rid of one of the problems it seems, but I still get the following response:

```
Could not open input file: php
```

**Edit:**

I was told by someone that the second php in my command shouldn't be there. Instead I should write:

> php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini app/console
>   generate:bundle

It seems like the second error was caused by a noobish typo by me, and now everything is working.

Comment: I've never liked MAMP. Try Zend Server CE instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Phil! As it seems there is only one problem left now I'll see if there is some way to fix it, but I don't find one I'll definitely try Zend Server CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch MAMP to use APC from the MAMP preferences menu, that worked for me! Make sure you restart apache after making the change.

Comment: Thank you so much @whistlergreg! Now my problem is cut in half it seems, but I still get "Could not open input file: php". Any idea why that could be?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: With Xcache 3.0, xcache.so is no longer a Zend Extension but a PHP extension

- remove zend_extension = */xcache.so
- load it using extension = xcache.so

This might be why the error is being thrown:

> The main cause for the error is because of **outdated build** of XCache
>   (not related to its actual version though), that mostly happens when
>   user upgrades PHP version. When compiling and building XCache, it’s
>   been associated with the version of Zend Engine API that exists on the
>   system at the time.
>
> When PHP is updated or upgraded, the Zend Engine API is updated too, causing XCache module to fail as the version no longer matched.
>
> The **solution** for the Zend Engine API version is newer error is pretty
>   simple. Just download, compile and install XCache again will fix and
>   resolve the issue permanently (until new PHP major version update). 1

Comment: Thanks for answering! By the time I saw this answer (and also before it was written) I had already changed to Ubuntu, and I didn't meet the problem there. But hopefully and probably this has been and will be of help to several others who meet the same problem.